# inserting values into table fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    function db_insert_article($flag,$url,$sentiment,$category,$title,$time,$rt_count,$tweet_count,$img_url)
    {
                    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        return;
                    }
                $today = date("Ymd"); 

    $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO frrole_popular_article (`url`, `sentiment`, `title` , `time` , `img_url` , `rt_count` , `tweet_count`, `today`) VALUES ('".$url."','".$sentiment."','".$title."','".$time."','".$img_url."','".$rt_count."','".$tweet_count."','".$today."')";
                        if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
                        {
                            //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                        }
 }
```

TAble structure:

[image]

Everything looks alright. Then why it does not insert into table? below this I have other queries which inserts into table successfully. IT also does not show any error.

**UPdate1** : This query works fine which is just below above code

```
            $insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO frrole_article_sentiment (`url`, `sentiment`, `category`, `title` , `time` , `img_url` , `rt_count` , `tweet_count`, `today`) VALUES ('".$url."','".$sentiment."','".$category."','".$title."','".$time."','".$img_url."','".$rt_count."','".$tweet_count."','".$today."')";

            if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery2))

            {

                //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

            }
```

**UPDATE2**

```
$insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO frrole_popular_article (`url` , `sentiment`, `img_url` , `title` , `rt_count` , `tweet_count`, `time` , `today`) VALUES ('".$url."','".$sentiment."','".$img_url."','".$title."','".$rt_count."','".$tweet_count."','".$time."','".$today."')";
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not pass your `$con` into the function?

Comment: I suggest you to print your query on the page, and to manually try it in phpMyAdmin, and check if some error occurs.
If it happens, you'll know what's wrong. if it doesn't, you know the query is not the problem

Comment: Did you try it without using your `db_insert_article()` function? Although it may or may not play a role, the variables' order in your function does not match what you have in your query. You could also try putting backticks around your table's name, but that's highly unlikely to change it; although it has for me in certain past cases.

Comment: @Stormsson: WHILE INsertig manually via query in mysql it works fie

Comment: @Fred-ii-: order does not make difference

Comment: That's why I phrased it as "Although it may or `may not` play a role..." ;-) but did you try it without the function?

Comment: ok, then you probably have something wrong with the connection: the 4th parameter is the database name and it is quite odd from here: is 'mysql' the correct db name?

Comment: Yes db name is correct @Stromsson

Comment: Also, @Programming_crazy , you are mentioning that later in your code you have other queries that insert into the table succesfully.
Could you add to the question those queries so that we can confront them?
Could you also add to the question the query that is printed on screen?

Comment: I updated  it @Stormsson

Comment: I'd like to know "how and where" you're calling the `db_insert_article()` function.

Comment: how is $con created in the second query ?
or better: use pastebin or something to paste the whole code. It looks like some mistake in the code

Comment: @Stormsson: please see entire code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c70e711e913d1c85546

Comment: @Fred-ii-: please see: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c70e711e913d1c85546

Comment: It seems like you're trying to call your function `before` it's been declared.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: that is not the issue. function getting called correctly. In function uutof 3 queries 2 works fine.

Comment: well it wouldn't execute neither the following queries...
i'm quite baffled. it could be something data-related.
Can you print somewhere the full query?

Comment: I spotted a stray brace `}` just below `//DEcode twitter tiny url to get long url` that could break your code.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to insert with:

```
$insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO frrole_article_sentiment
     (`url`, `sentiment`, `category`,
      `title` , `time` , `img_url` ,
    `rt_count` , `tweet_count`, `today`) 
        VALUES ....
```

but when you make `select * from frrole_article_sentiment;` it returned you 8 columns and you are trying to insert in 9 columns, in other words in your state `insert into....` you are trying to insert into `CATEGORY` attribute but it doesn't exist in the table